# Google Talk API for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios4, gdata-api

Does anyone know how to connect to Google Talk using GData API. IS there a better api for iphone development for connection to Google Talk? I have been looking thru the examples I downloaded for the API but I don't see any support.

[This](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/listbeen) is what I have been looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Talk uses XMPP, and it has no GData API.

I suggest you look at: http://code.google.com/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html