# Is it possible to integrate a google talk api in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, google-talk

I want to know whether it is possible to integrate a google talk api in one of my iphone tabs. Searched a lot but couldn't find any suitable answers

Comment: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550784/google-talk-api-for-iphone